# How to prevent cookie access from browser console?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, browser, angular9

Using `document.cookie` I can read and manipulate the value of cookie
from the browsers console.

How can I prevent that?

[image: here is the result]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with setting the cookies `HttpOnly` flag? Setting this should disable all JS access to the cookie. Check this: https://www.ictshore.com/ict-basics/httponly-cookie/

Comment: but how to pass that in setCookieValue method of "ngx-cookie-service"

Comment: HttpOnly flag is to be set by the server, not the client. What do you have on the server side?

Comment: but how can i prevent access from browser console in angular

Comment: Honestly - if HttpOnly does not work than nothing will. The browser is sometimes named the user agent, because it belongs to the user. The user is able to do everything with the requests/responses. EVERYTHING. No console access can prevent this.